# (php) if condition not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I am going crazy here. The following simple if-condition does not produce the right output.

```
$xxx = 1;
if($xxx == 1)
    define('DEBUG', true);
else
    define('DEBUG', false);
var_dump($xxx);
var_dump(DEBUG);
die();
```

Output:

```
int(1)
bool(false)
```

I see absolutely no reason why the DEBUG constant is not being set to true.
PHP's type juggling should allow this if-statement. And even if I put an intval in front of the variable, it still produces false as output.

Edit 2:
I copied the exact code from above into a new file and it produces the expected output.
So I don't know what is going on...

Comment: the 1 in `string(1)` is an indication of the length of the string, not its value. try `echo $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'];` to see what its value actually is.

Comment: Why don't you cast your `$vbulletin->userinfo['userid']` as an int anyway?

Comment: it seems, that there is something missing in your debug output for `userid`: As Brian mentioned the `(1)` indicates the length, but usually the content follows after that.

Comment: Must be some caching issue. Must be server-side. I changed the code entirely, refreshed the page (by holding down the shift key) and it still produces the old output. Happens in all browsers.

Comment: Try a var_dump on `DEBUG` (or `print_r(get_defined_constants());`) before you define it and see what the output is in both cases. It appears that you can "redefine" if one define statement includes the is_case_sensitive flag...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var_dump($vbulletin->userinfo['userid']);
```

Output :

```
string(1)
```

Your string length is one, and it seems to be empty (a space ?).

Answer (score 2):

```
$vbulletin  = new stdClass();
$vbulletin->userinfo    = array('userid' =>  1);

if(1 == $vbulletin->userinfo['userid'])
    define('DEBUG', true);
else
    define('DEBUG', false);
var_dump(DEBUG);
echo "\n";
var_dump($vbulletin->userinfo['userid']);
```

There isn't anything wrong with your code. Running the above code gives me

```
bool(true) int(1)
```

I suspect your `$vbulletin->userinfo['userid']` variable has a different value to what you think it has

**EDIT**

When I change it to

```
$vbulletin->userinfo    = array('userid' =>  '1');
```

I get `string(1) "1"`. You're string appears to be empty, and that's the reason it's failing.

Comment: A var_dump of the vbulletin variable produces `string(1) "1"`, so I don't see it.

Comment: @reggie, Try explicitly setting the value just above the condition and see. If it work then the data in your variable is off. You can focus on it next

Comment: @reggie, just to confirm, You tried setting the value explicitly _just above the IF condition_ and it still did not evaluate properly? At this my recommendation would be to install Eclipse + Xdebug and put on your debugger hat :)

Comment: Yes, I explicitly defined the value just above the if-statement. I am a Zend certified developer, and this issue is highly stupid and annoying me to the extreme. I can't make any sense of the results. When I paste it into a separate document that contains only code above, it works. It makes no sense.

Comment: @reggie, happens to all of us. Just start up the debugger and see what's actually in there at run time.